# Displaying Data from Firebase in TableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code in one of my VC's (as part of my larger project). One of my Firebase DB references is called `Sell_Request`. It has three children (`name`, `latitude` and `longitude`), but I'm only concerned with `name` for right now.

I am trying to add it to a String array and am also printing it to the console. I am seeing the names being printed to the console, but I'm not getting the names printed in the individual cells.

Thanks for looking.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class RequestVC: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var sellerUserNames = [String]()

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "backToMain" {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = manager.location?.coordinate {
            let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
            databaseRef.child("Sell_Request").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (FIRDataSnapshot) in

                if let data = FIRDataSnapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                    if let name = data[Constants.NAME] as? String {
                                self.sellerUserNames.append(name)
                                print(name)
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return sellerUserNames.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = sellerUserNames[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Can you check your count is not 0.A After your print line reload table on main thread.

Comment: Hi, you need to reload your tableview. Add a reference of your tableview name it tableView, then at the end of your if let data statement add self.tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Thanks for your response...I'm still a little new to this. Did you mean creating a variable (var tableView: UITableView!) or creating an IBOutlet (@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!), or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call `tableView.reloadData()` after you append the name to the `sellerUserNames` array, change your function to this...

```
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = manager.location?.coordinate {
        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        sellerUserNames.removeAll()
        databaseRef.child("Sell_Request").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (FIRDataSnapshot) in

            if let data = FIRDataSnapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                if let name = data[Constants.NAME] as? String {
                            self.sellerUserNames.append(name)
                            print(name)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
```

**Edit**

where/when you want to call `sellerUserNames.removeAll()` depends on your code and the life cycle of your table view, but I have edited my code above to add it in where it is most likely appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to do it...I seem to have another problem, though. I am getting the same names repeating themselves. I looked at some related SO questions, and it seems like calling                          self.sellerUserNames.removeAll() somewhere in the function should provide a quick fix to the problem, which it did...But it also only shows the first name.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a call to `sellerUserNames.removeAll()` which should solve that problem

Answer (score 0):

`TableView` need to reload after data source has changes i.e `sellerUserNames` in your code. So after you append the name to `sellerUserNames`, you need to reload the tableview.

Add this line of code after you append the name.

`self.tableView.reloadData()`